# Issue in localization in android app message show in reverse in RTL

Tags: android, kotlin, localization

IMAGE of error string reverse.  Issue in localization in android app message show in reverse in RTL.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add a [mre]. Without code all we can do is look at the picture and guess how it was coded.

Comment: Replace all the occurrences of layout attributes that contains ‘left’ and ‘right’ to ‘start’ and ‘end’ respectively. For example, android:paddingLeft should become android:paddingStart

Answer (score 0):

If you have already set application to support RTL (`android:supportsRtl="true"`) then set `textAligment` at this view inside the `xml` file.

```
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```